# chromedriver_autoinstaller on MacOS

Tags: macos, selenium, google-chrome, driver

I do not understand why the module does not seem to work. I am rather new with selenium, so maybe I'm doing something wrong here? I am running MacOS, and I'm thinking maybe it has something to do with it looking for an .exe file, however the module states that it works for MacOS. Any suggestions as to how I can fix this error?

I tried this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller

chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()
```

However I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-9d0dc3cdfe17> in <module>
----> 1 chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/chromedriver_autoinstaller/utils.py in get_linux_executable_path()
    151         if path is not None:
    152             return path
--> 153     raise ValueError("No chrome executable found on PATH")
    154 
    155 

ValueError: No chrome executable found on PATH
```

Comment: My suggestion is instead of chromedriver_autoinstaller use WebDriverManager.

Comment: Once again I get an error, I can see that once again it mentions linux64, however I am running on a Mac. The error I get is: WebDriverException: Message: Service /root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/107.0.5304/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -6

Answer (score 0):

I think the autoinstaller is mixing MacOS with Linux distribution. May be the way theъ autodect the OS is buggy.

Use the WebDriverManager to manage the drivers and you wont have this issue.

Install webdriver manager running this in the console:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

And then try with this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however when I do this I get the following error:
WebDriverException: Message: Service /root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/107.0.5304/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -6

Comment: Do you have chrome browser installed on your Mac and what is the version of the browser?